# Problem with LM1085 3-A regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, 5v

I've been trying to build a 5V voltage regulator for a PCB that converts a input voltage from 10 to 30V. I've been searching on internet and I've found that the LM1085 was suitable for this case, with a maximum output of 3A that its fine. The problem is that it just outputs the same voltage of the input instead of the wanted 5V. I've been connected a LED with a resistor to make sure that it has the minimum current of 5-10mA and still outputs 22V.

These are the connections that I have done to the chip(the same that are indicated in its datasheet).

Can somebody tell me why it doesn't work?

Thank you in advance.

[image: Schematic of the wiring]

Comment: Are you using the "Adjustable" version (LM1085-ADJ) or the fixed 5V version (LM1085-5.0)? The results you're seeing seem to indicate that you're using the fixed 5V version with that circuit which is intended for the adjustable version.

Comment: Also check the obvious...the In, Out and Adj pins are the ones you think they are.

Comment: The pins are checked, and it's the LM1085IT-12/NOPB version. I can suppose that this version is 12V fixed?

Comment: The IT-12/NOPB indeed means "industrial temperature, 12v fixed output, no-lead construction."

Comment: Since you're gonna order some parts, [get a switcher instead](https://www.mouser.fr/Power/DC-DC-Converters/Non-Isolated-DC-DC-Converters/_/N-brvxx?P=1yxt7eu&Rl=brvxxZgjdht2Z1y7m09rZ1y7m03wSGT) it will be cheaper than the heat sink you'll need on a LM1085 for 30V input...

Comment: Just as it hasn't been mentioned yet, on the fixed version, the ADJ pin will in fact be GND. Make sure you don't have that resistor divider there.